# Microsoft Surface Pro Earthing Issue

Tags: power, microsoft-surface-pro, ground

I have the original 128GB Microsoft Surface Pro. However, when I plug it in to charge, I get small electric shocks from the corners of the device. I have already tried different power supplies. Could this be an issue with the Earthing of the device? Also, is this a common problem with Surface Tablets?

Comment: A quick google search may provide you more evidence than you'll get here :  http://www.geek.com/microsoft/surface-pro-owners-report-shocks-while-charging-1540717/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* a fairly common issue amongst Surface Pro tables. You can call Microsoft support, explain the problem and they will send you a new tablet ([source](http://www.geek.com/microsoft/surface-pro-owners-report-shocks-while-charging-1540717/)).